# How to see envelope in qgis?

Tags: qgis

I am using JTS library functions to get an envelope around lat,long.
Now I have the envelope but I can't find an option in qgis to enter the coordinates of an envelope and see if correct BBox is created or not.

Env[  this.minx    :    this.maxx,     this.miny   :    this.maxy ]

Env[-50004.9793102 : 49995.0206898, -49963.5205293 : 50036.4794707]

I should see the bbox drawn on the osm layer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to print your geometry in WKT format then copy/paste the string into QGIS.

#### Steps

Suppose you've got an Envelope instance using JTS.
The following code will convert your Envelope instance to Geometry, so that it can be printed in WKT format.

```java
Envelope yourEnvelope;
final GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
System.out.println(geometryFactory.toGeometry(yourEnvelope));
```

You will get a string looks like:
`POLYGON ((1.2 9.5, 1.2 8.1, 4.7 8.1, 4.7 9.5, 1.2 9.5))`

Install QGIS plugin [QuickWKT](https://www.itopen.it/wkt-on-the-fly-qgis-plugin/)

Paste your string into QuickWKT
[image: QuickWKT screenshot in QGIS]

You got your bounding box drawn in QGIS.